# Kendo UI Treeview datasource not binding to all items in datasource

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

Brand new to Kendo UI and looking to evaluate against another UI framework. I have a js array that I want to populate in the treeview. I am passing the array to the function that creates the kendotreeview on a selector. I need to transform the array before adding to the HierarchicalDataSource. It works fine on the first pass, but when another object is added to the array, and I call the function again, the tree continues to display only the bottom object in the array. Here is the code:

```
var len = data.ar.length,
    dAR = [];

for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) { // Transform my passed array into one appropriate for the tree
    var v = data.ar[i],
        iLen = v.items.length,
        iAR = [],
        dMap = {
            text: v.type + ' (' + v.resultCount + ')',
            child: v.child,
            type: v.type,
            items: iAR
        };

    for(var ii = 0; ii < iLen; ii++) {
        var vv = v.items[ii], 
            iMap = {
                text: vv.type + ' (' + vv.qty + ')',
                child: vv.child,
                par: vv.parent,
                parentType: vv.parentType,
                type: vv.type
            };

        dMap.items.push(iMap);
    }
    dAR.push(dMap);
}

var treeData = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
    data: dAR
});

var treeview = $(".searchResultsList").data("kendoTreeView"); 
if(treeview !== undefined) {
    treeview.destroy();
}

$(".searchResultsList").kendoTreeView({
    dataSource: treeData,
    select: function(e) {
        var itm = this.dataItem(e.node);
        selectionChange(itm);
    }
});
```

The tree appears and functions correctly until adding additional objects to the array. If I add static data to the HierarchicalDataSource, it works good with multiple objects in the array. That leads me to believe that the issue is coming from the way I'm transforming the array contents that are passed. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is the entire block of code above in a function that gets called when you add an item to the array? You shouldn't need to `.dispose()` and re-create the treeview. You can just call `treeview.setDataSource(treeData);` but that probably isn't the cause of your problem.

Comment: Correct. The entire tree is built on demand in a function. There are additional private methods within the function (ie, the selectionChange method called). I fixed the issue by completely destroying the tree, then calling .remove() on the DOM element via jQuery. I didn't know about the 'setDataSource' method! That would have been much easier! In the previous library we were using, we could continue to call the function and the tree instance would refresh automatically. Thanks for your help.